# Can the Hunter subclass use their Volley feature with a melee weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, actions, ranger

The Ranger subclass in D&D 5e, [Hunter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Hunter), has an 11th-level feature called Multiattack which allows them to pick Volley or Whirlwind.

> **Volley.**
> You can use your action to make a ranged attack against any number of creatures within 10 feet of a point you can see within your weapon’s range. You must have ammunition for each target, as normal, and you make a separate attack roll for each target.

Is there anything that would allow a Hunter to use any melee weapons, such as a glaive, to perform a "volley" of stabs by targeting a point within their weapon's reach (such as in front of them) and targeting the creatures within 10 feet of that point to perform a "range attack" despite using a melee weapon?

Comment: Hello there! Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] in case you need any guidance for posting questions and answers on this site! Happy gaming!

Comment: To give some feedback here, two answers have pointed out that the feature description says “ranged attack” and talks about “ammunition”, which, of course, a glaive is not. Which makes me wonder if we are missing something here. Was there some reason you had in mind for why it might work to use a melee attack when the description says ranged attack? (I think the downvotes here are because it seems like a pretty obvious question.)

Comment: I think the question isn't asking if the feature let's you use a melee weapon, the answer to that is obvious. Rather it is asking if some other feature might transform this to allow use of a melee weapon. Example might be something that says 'melee weapon attacks can count as ranged weapon attacks for you'. This is quite common in computer games.

Comment: @SeriousBri Maybe you're right, but as it is written the question seems to have an obvious answer again..

Comment: @Eddymage as written it is asking "is there anything" not "am I reading it right" which is how you are interpreting it. To people who know DND well it might be obvious, but many systems have abilities which maybe morph as you level up or get upgraded in some manner, it isn't all that obvious to a newbie and just repeating the question back to them seems valueless to me.

Comment: @SeriousBri No I mean that the answer is even in the question, when listing the options for Multiattack. The only thing that should be clarified by OP is what they mean by "ahead of them".

Comment: I reclarified what I meant by ahead of the Hunter.

Answer (score 13):

#### No.

The quoted rules say (emphases mine):

> **Volley.**
> You can use your action to make a **ranged attack** against any number of creatures within 10 feet of a point you can see within your **weapon’s range**.

The feature requires explicitly a ranged attack, moreover it mentions the weapon's *range*, not the attack's reach.

#### The Whirlwind attack option does not allow it either: one cannot attack enemies at more than 5 feet.

The text of *Whirlwind Attack* says (emphasis mine):

> You can use your action to make a melee attack against any number of creatures **within 5 feet of you**, with a separate attack roll for each target.

Hence, even the glaive's reach is 10 feet, a Ranger with *Whirlwind Attack* can attack enemies only within 5 feet of them.

Answer (score 1):

### You can only use the volley with ranged weapons that use ammunition

The volley has two conditions for its use

1. it must be a ranged attack
2. it must use ammuntion

> You can use your action to make **a ranged attack** against any number of creatures within 10 feet of a point you can see within your weapon’s range. **You must have ammunition for each target**, as normal, and you make a separate attack roll for each target.

A pure melee weapon, such as a glaive, can not be used for the volley, as it violates both conditions.

While some melee weapons, such as a dagger, light hammer, or handaxe have the *thrown* property, which allows you to use them for ranged attacks, they do not have the ammuntion property, so even those weapons cannot be used for a volley. Page 146, PHB:

> ***Ammunition***. You can use a weapon that has the ammunition property to make a ranged attack only if you have ammunition to fire from the weapon. Each time you attack with the weapon, you expend one piece of ammunition. Drawing the ammunition from a quiver, case, or other container is part of the attack.

While this is the [technical rules-as-written answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88778/can-thrown-weapons-be-used-for-the-hunter-rangers-volley-feature) for thrown weapons, check with your DM. They may be up for allowing you to throw multiple daggers or such, in case you have them in a belt to throw. This should not be unbalancing, as a bow tends to deal as much or more damage than these weapons, and either one will suffer disadavantage if used in close combat, so it is more of a flavor question to allow this or not.

Comment: But if you have 5 daggers, can you target 5 enemies?

Comment: I do not think so, as daggers are not ammuntion.

Comment: I am not sure if in this case "ammunition" stands for the property, or if you must have enough weapons for all the attacks

Comment: Related: [Can thrown weapons be used for the Hunter ranger's Volley feature?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/88778/63061)

Comment: I think ammunition generally refers to something that is used with a weapon, not the weapon itself, for examplel the dictionary defines it (more modernly) as "a supply or quantity of bullets and shells". The linked answer also supports that technical reading, RAW. Of course the DM may rule otherwise; I'll add that to the answer.